# Populating a 2D Array with unique (non-random) values

Tags: java, multidimensional-array

Is there a way to populate a 2D Array with unique, nonrandom values? The compiler won't allow something like:

```
int[][] myArray=new int[5][5];

myArray[0]=new int[] {2, 1, 1, 1, 1};
```

to happen, and all of the tutorials I've seen on this have related to adding random numbers or populating the array from the start(not applicable to me, as my program depends on user input to know what number values to add). If this isn't possible, is there another method I should be using?

Comment: Unique values to each Row of the 2D Array or to the entire 2D Array (Rows and Columns)?

Comment: To clarify, unique values to each row of the 2D array.

Answer (score 0):

You should use a nested for loop:

```
for(i=0;i<arr.lenght;i++)
   for(j=0;j<arr.lenght;j++)
```

After doing your nested loop, add something like this:
    myArray[i][j]= userInput.next(); //assuming you are using Scanner class

what the nested loop does is iterate through each of the "spaces" the array has and because you are asking the user to input something each time, your array will populate in each "space" with the desired input.

Hope this helps.(ignore my edits, totally misread)

Answer (score 0):

You can fill your 2D Integer (int) Array with either unique values throughout the entire Array or unique values only for each Row of the Array. There are several ways to do this sort of thing but we'll just stick with basic methods. The code is well commented:

> **User fills 2D Integer Array with Unique Rows only:**

```
    // Setup for Keyboard input to Console.
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in); 

    // System Line Separator used in console display.
    String ls = System.lineSeparator();
    // Declare and initialize a 2D Object Array.
    // We need to use Object so that all initialized
    // elements will be null rather than 0 since 0
    // could be supplied and will need to be checked
    // for Unique. Since a 2D int array by default 
    // initializes all elements to 0, a supplied 0
    // will never be considered Unique. 
    Object[][] myArray = new Object[5][5];

    // Have User fill our 2D Array...
    for (int row = 0; row < myArray.length; row++) {
        // Display the Row User will be on to fill.
        System.out.println(ls + "Enter values for Row #" + (row+1) + 
                           " of " + myArray.length);

        // Allow User to fill each column of the current Row...
        for (int column = 0; column < myArray[row].length; column++) {
            // Flag to indicate Uniqueness.
            boolean unique = false; 
            // Integer variable to hold what the User enters in console
            int value = 0;
            // Continue looping to ensure the User supplied a proper 
            // integer value which is unique to the current 2D Array
            // Row only.
            while (!unique) {
                // Display the Column User will be on to fill.
                System.out.print("Column #" + (column+1) + " value: --> ");
                // Trap User entries that are not Integer values. If any alpha
                // characters are supplied with the value then an exception is
                // automatically thrown which we trap.
                try {
                    // Get input from User...
                    value = input.nextInt(); 
                } catch (Exception ex) {
                    // Inform the User of an improper entry if an exception was thrown.
                    System.err.println("You must supply an Integer value. Try again...");
                    input.nextLine();  // Clear Scanner buffer
                    // Allow User to try another entry for the same Column
                    continue;   
                }

                // See if the supplied value is already contained within the 
                // current array Row...
                for (int j = 0; j < myArray[row].length; j++) {
                    // Stop checking if we hit null. Nothing there yet.
                    if (myArray[row][j] == null) { 
                        unique = true; 
                        break; 
                    }
                    // If a row's column element equals supplied value...
                    else if ((int)myArray[row][j] == value) { 
                        // Value is not Unique
                        unique = false;
                        System.err.println("Value is not unique to Row #" + 
                                           (row+1) + " - Try Again...");
                        break; // Break out of checking early
                    }
                    // The supplied value is unique.
                    else { 
                        unique = true; 
                    }
                }
            }
            //Place the value into the current 
            // Column for the current Row
            myArray[row][column] = value;
        }
    }

    // Convert the 2D Object Array to a 2D int Array
    int[][] intArray = new int[myArray.length][myArray[0].length];
    for (int i = 0;i < myArray.length; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < myArray[i].length; j++) {
            intArray[i][j] = (int)myArray[i][j]; // Cast to int
        }
    }

    // Display the 2D Array in Console Window...
    System.out.println(ls + "2D Integer Array Contents:");
    for (int i = 0; i < intArray.length; i++) {
        System.out.println("Row #" + (i+1) + ":  " + Arrays.toString(intArray[i]));
    }
}
```

> **User fills 2D Integer Array with Unique values throughout the entire Array:**

```
// Setup for Keyboard input to Console.
Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
// System Line Separator used in console display.
String ls = System.lineSeparator();
// Declare and initialize a 2D Object Array.
// We need to use Object so that all initialized
// elements will be null rather than 0 since 0
// could be supplied and will need to be checked
// for Unique. Since a 2D int array by default 
// initializes all elements to 0, a supplied 0
// will never be considered Unique. 
Object[][] myArray = new Object[5][5];

// Have User fill our 2D Array...
for (int row = 0; row < myArray.length; row++) {
    // Display the Row User will be on to fill.
    System.out.println(ls + "Enter values for Row #" + (row+1) + 
                        " of " + myArray.length);

    // Allow User to fill each column of the current Row...
    for (int column = 0; column < myArray[row].length; column++) {
        // Flag to indicate Uniqueness.
        boolean unique = false;
        // Integer variable to hold what the User enters in console
        int value = 0;
        // Continue looping to ensure the User supplied a proper 
        // integer value which is unique to the ENTIRE 2D Array.
        while (!unique) {
            // Display the Column User will be on to fill.
            System.out.print("Column #" + (column+1) + " value: --> ");
            // Trap User entries that are not Integer values. If any alpha
            // characters are supplied with the value then an exception is
            // automatically thrown which we trap.
            try {
                // Get input from User...
                value = input.nextInt(); 
            } catch (Exception ex) {
                // Inform the User of an improper entry if an exception was thrown.
                System.err.println("You must supply an Integer value. Try again...");
                input.nextLine();  // Clear Scanner buffer
                // Allow User to try another entry for the same Column
                continue;
            }
            // Flag to hold when a match is found. This flag will allow 
            // us to break out the the for loops faster
            boolean match = false;
           // See if value is already contained within the array.
           // Iterate Rows...
           for (int i = 0; i < myArray.length; i++) {
                // Iterate the Columns for each Row...
                for (int j = 0; j < myArray[i].length; j++) {
                    // Stop checking if we hit null. Nothing there yet.
                    if (myArray[i][j] == null) { 
                        break; 
                    }
                    // If a row's column element equals supplied value...
                    else if ((int)myArray[i][j] == value) { 
                        match = true;  // A match was detected - Not Unique
                        System.err.println("Value is not Unique - Try Again...");
                        break;      // Break out of checking early
                    }
                }
                if (match) { break; } // Break out of outer loop is there was a match
            }
            unique = !match;  // unique flag is to be oposite of what match contains
        }
        myArray[row][column] = value; // Add supplied value to array
    }
}

// Convert the 2D Object Array to a 2D int Array
int[][] intArray = new int[myArray.length][myArray[0].length];
for (int i = 0;i < myArray.length; i++) {
   for (int j = 0; j < myArray[i].length; j++) {
       intArray[i][j] = (int)myArray[i][j]; // Cast to int
   }
}

// Display the 2D Array...
System.out.println(ls + "2D Integer Array Contents:");
for (int i = 0; i < intArray.length; i++) {
     System.out.println("Row #" + (i+1) + ":  " + Arrays.toString(intArray[i]));
}
```